Why does this BigQuery query keep returning Invalid date: '20.02.2017'
Here is the query I am running
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST(Date AS Date)) AS Year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(Date AS Date)) AS Month,
    ProductId,
    ROUND(MAX(UnitPrice),2) AS UnitPrice,
    SUM(Quantity) AS UnitsSold
FROM `mineral-anchor-426102-d8.sales.sales_info`
GROUP BY  
  Year,  
  Month,
  ProductId
ORDER BY  Year,  Month,  ProductId;

Data Preview

Here are the details of the data

I have tried using DATE_FORMAT and still got this error. Is there anything I am missing?

DATE_FORMAT converts from date to string, the opposite of what you want. Is it too late to just fix the column type and prevent all this type fiddling?

You need to use
PARSE_DATE so you can specify the format your date string is in:
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y',  Date))

